# End-to-end "group chat" encryption

Tags: encryption

I have a case here, where I need to encrypt messages to a team/group. Everyone in the group can create a new message, and everyone else in the group can read/edit/delete that message. I want the following things:

1. Encrypted messages
2. Decryptable by everyone in a group (no one else can unlock it)
3. Group members can read/edit each message
4. No re-use of messages (like storing all the team members' public keys and then encrypt all messages with their public key), as that wouldn't work in this case
5. Possible to add a new member to the group and give that member access to all previous messages

The main property of this is security. I do not want anyone to be able to access the messages.

Here's a possible problem: If the whole database gets dropped and someone already has an account on that site, that said user should NOT be able to just add himself to that group, to display all the passwords stored in that group (like if the person recreates the application using the database). The messages would need to be encrypted somehow, that no one (not even with the database in hand) can access the encrypted messages.

What am I looking at doing here? It's a pretty unique case I think.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-use of messages"?  How is storing other users' public keys re-use of a message?

Comment: @cloudfeet What I mean by that, is I would have to decrypt all messages and encrypt them with the user's public key. Basically store (USER * MESSAGES) amount of messages in the server. This would be ideal, as you can only decrypt the messages using the user's private key, but it's not efficient at all.

Comment: You will not find better security than Signal for messaging: https://support.whispersystems.org/hc/en-us/articles/216567598-How-do-I-start-a-group-chat-
However I'm afraid your question is out of topic on this SE.

Comment: PS: If you want a methodology instead of a product, you should check the white papers of Open Whisper Systems.

Comment: @A.Hersean Thanks! The white paper said "A client wishing to send a message to a group of users transmits a single message, which is then distributed N times to the N different group members by the server." - That basically means, I would encrypt all messages using their public keys, right?

Comment: @MortenMoulder - you rarely encrypt the whole message using public keys.  Instead, you encrypt symmetrically, and encrypt the symmetric key using public key.  This means that if you're sending to each person, you only need to encrypt the main message once, so the size is not (USER * MESSAGES), it's (MESSAGES + USER * KEY).

Comment: @cloudfeet Right, so you encrypt the message with something like AES, then encrypt the AES key (randomly generated) with the public keys and distribute that to the users. Right?

Comment: @MortenMoulder Yep.  That's what [this diagram](https://whispersystems.org/blog/images/groups-pairwise-optimize.png) in the Whisper blog link from my answer shows them doing, although they're obviously using their much more powerful protocol instead of plain public-key encryption.  But basically yes - the symmetrically-encrypted message can be essentially sent as a broadcast, while the (shorter) decryption key is sent+encrypted one-to-one.

Comment: @cloudfeet Cool! So let's imagine I want to distribute a new message for the entire group (let's say 10 people), I would then ask the server for all their public keys, generate a random AES key, encrypt the message with said AES key, send the encrypted message to the server, loop over each public key and encrypt the AES with their public key (`n_Pub(AES_KEY)`) and give the AES key to each user, which they can decrypt using their private key and then they have the AES key to decrypt the final message? I hope that makes sense haha.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Sounds about right.  Whether you ask the server for the public keys or include them in the "join" notification (posted by whoever invited them) so they can be stored on the client is a matter of how much you want to trust the server.  You could also do things like include the hash of previously-seen messages in each message, so that if one of the group members is an admin they can't mess with the message history, and other tricks like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55409/discussion-between-cloudfeet-and-mortenmoulder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with your last constraint: if the database is compromised, then attacker must not be able to extract a key from the database and decrypt messages.  A simple way to ensure this is make sure **the key is not in the database**.  That is, whatever keys/etc. are required to decrypt the messages are stored by each client, not centrally.

You said you don't want to encrypt each message for each person using their public key.  Is a per-person symmetric key also out?  The disadvantage there is that in an N-person group each message would have N signatures, and there would need to be N<sup>2</sup> keys - so this is not ideal for large groups.

Instead, what if there was a single "group key", which everybody uses to encrypt their messages?  Everybody in this group would have this key.  Part of "joining" a group is where an existing member shares their copy of the key with you.  To prove authorship (if that's desired) you could *sign* each message with the public key of the author - edited messages would be signed with the public key of the editor.

If there's a single group key, you would need to rotate this key whenever someone got booted out from the group.  This would require a user commonly-accepted as a "group administrator" sending a message to each individual member telling them the new key.  In order for new members to be able to read the entire history, it could make sense for the old key to be encrypted with the new key and posted to the group (possibly as part of the "X has left the group" notification), so that new members can follow the message history back across this boundary.

So: a single group key stored in the clients not the servers, keys replaced whenever a member leaves the group and sent to each member (public-key encryted) by an admin, and each message/edit optionally signed by public key (different from the previous one, because you never sign and encrypt with the same key).  This seems to me like it would fit your requirements,  but it falls short on some other requirements - the gold standard is Whisper Systems, so you could [read about](https://whispersystems.org/blog/private-groups/) how they do things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would using a "group key" work? I assume it would be stored somewhere, or shared among everyone off-site, right? Isn't sharing private keys illegal in some sense? What if someone decides to steal that private key? I basically want each person logged in to be able to decrypt the message with their own login, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The read about Whisper Systems shows a server being the "middleman" doing the encryption. Would something like this be possible to do client side?

Comment: Whisper Systems / Signal does not do any encryption on the server.  All encryption/decryption is done on the client, and the server just distributes encrypted messages to the appropriate recipients.

Comment: Oh okay, that's cool! Thanks, I've learned a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it in a while, but Threema is a good end-to-end encryption tool that can do group chats. Can't speak to the rest.

https://threema.ch/en/faq/groupchat

Comment: I'm looking for a methodology I can implement in my own application :)

Comment: They use the open source Signal Protocl. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol Check it out, it might help.

Comment: You can also check out the white papers for ideas https://threema.ch/press-files/cryptography_whitepaper.pdf

Comment: Hmm I don't think this can work in this case, as they use user->user2 encryption (basically encrypting the message using the person's public key).